# How can I fix this error during node project installation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am having trouble installing a node.js and mongodb project. 
I have install all the node modules and mongodb.
After running monogodb server I cannot run node server.
And I get the following error.

```
Sajals-Air:library-mgmt isajal07$ node index
library_system listening on port 3000
    {
  "res": {
    "statusCode": 302
  },
  "req": {
    "url": "/",
    "headers": {
      "host": "localhost:3000",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
      "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36",
      "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
      "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
      "cookie": "librarySys=s%3AXGrItDjCvFlXbYPemPtGfpZXvvXQAvx8.SSZDbc9Vjx2byRcpeOoRDvxz4PZ1lUeFRmyEmw6XeNc"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "httpVersion": "1.1",
    "originalUrl": "/",
    "query": {}
  },
  "responseTime": 4,
  "level": "info",
  "message": "HTTP GET /"
}
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'logs/success.log'
Emitted 'error' event at:
at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/Users/isajal07/Desktop/library-mgmt/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js:491:16)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:272:12)
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
```

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'logs/success.log'
clearly tells the issue.